# Use of '<span>' tag in lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, html

I'm building a lightning component and trying to use span in a `div`. My code is as below

```
<div class="subscribe slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-3">
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="slds-input" label="Sign up" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address">
  <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button></span>
  </input></div></div>
```

But the span is not rendering. That means button is showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close you `</input>` tag before `<Span>`

Try this and let us know if this works for you or  not

```
<div class="subscribe slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="slds-input" label="Sign up" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address"></input>
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Samir. its funny I tried earlier and it didn't worked. I tried again after your answer and it worked :).

Comment: Glad I could help.